# Setting up Products with Quantity Price points

Tags: opportunity-lineitem

Trying to setup products where the product list price would be different based on quantity.   Don't see any standard features for products/pricebooks that support this so thinking I would have to setup a separate product for each quantity price point and then perhaps add validation to ensure the qty is appropriate for the selected product price point.
Would prefer not to implement a custom object for this but any suggestions are most welcome.